# Firebase - issue with Auth during registration

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am new to firebase and have managed to successfully setup an authentication with email/ password based off what I have managed to gather from the documentation/ examples online. I've encountered some strange behaviour on register though. First of all here is my firebase auth code that sits in a React component function:

```
class SignupComponentInner extends Component { 
    toggleSignupLayoverAction(event){
        this.props.toggleSignupLayover("false")
    }
    signUp(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var firstName = $('.signup-first-name').val();
        var lastName = $('.signup-last-name').val();
        var userName = $('.signup-user-name').val();
        var password = $('.signup-user-password').val();
        var email = $('.signup-email').val();   

        var auth = firebase.auth();

        const promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).then(function(user) {

        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        user.updateProfile({
            displayName: userName,
        }).then(function() {
        // Update successful.

        // new db code here
        firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).set({
            firstName: firstName,
            lastName: lastName,
            userName: userName
        })
        // end new db code here

    }, function(error) {
        // An error happened.
    });  

}, function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    // [START_EXCLUDE]
    if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
        alert('The password is too weak.');
    } else {
        console.error(error);
    }
    // [END_EXCLUDE]
});

        promise.catch(e => console.log(e.message));   
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
           if(firebaseUser) {
               console.log("logged in");
               var sendUserId = firebaseUser.uid;
               this.props.logUserIn(sendUserId)
           } else {
               console.log("not logged in")
           }
        });
    }
    render() {
       return (
           <div onClick={this.toggleSignupLayoverAction.bind(this)} className="signup-cont-par">
           <div className="signup-component-inner">
               <div className="signup-component-content" onClick={cancelBubble.bind(this)}>
               <h2>Sign up today!</h2>
               <form className="signup-form-elem">
                    <input placeholder="First Name" className="signup-first-name" type="text"></input>
                    <input placeholder="Last Name" className="signup-last-name" type="text"></input>
                    <input placeholder="Username" className="signup-user-name" type="text"></input>
                    <input placeholder="Password" className="signup-user-password" type="password"></input>
                    <input placeholder="Email Address" className="signup-email" type="text"></input>
                    <button onClick={this.signUp.bind(this)}>Sign Up</button>
               </form>
                   </div>
           </div>
           </div>
           )
    }
}
```

So the registration part works exactly as it should but its the login part here that is causing issues:

```
        firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(firebaseUser => {
           if(firebaseUser) {
               console.log("logged in");
               var sendUserId = firebaseUser.uid;
               this.props.logUserIn(sendUserId)
           } else {
               console.log("not logged in")
           }
        });
```

It's basically executing twice as im getting console.log "logged in" twice on register. Not sure why that is?

The other issue is the function that it is calling from the props `this.props.logUserIn(sendUserId)` This function basically hides a "create account" CTA and replaces it with a hello {{username}}. The username updates on register but very strangely it will update to whatever username I registered on the previous register! Here is the logUserIn function if it helps:

```
logUserIn(userId) {
    var db = firebase.database();
    var ref = db.ref('/users/' + userId);

    console.log(userId);

     ref.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
         var userObject = snapshot.val();
         var loggedUserName = userObject.userName;
        this.setState({
            LoggedInUsername:loggedUserName
        })
     });

    this.setState({
        loggedInState:true,
        LoggedInId:userId,
        signingUp:"inactive"
    })
},
```

Here `loggedUserName`is a state that is passed down to the main component to show the username that has just been registered (the one that is incorrectly showing the previous registered person when it should be showing the latest). Not sure where I have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase maintains persistent connections with their servers so if you registered once, Firebase detects your browser and machine to be logged in for that newly created user. So, if you close the browser and then come back to your project on the SAME browser, Firebase still thinks you are logged in and hence, the `onAuthStateChanged` event handler is called.

Try it out for yourself and see what happens when you open up 2 different browsers.

To complete the whole authentication system, you need to have a logout function that will tell Firebase that this user has logged out (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth#next_steps)